# Sort array of objects in ascending by IP

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

i have diffuculties with this question. so i have an array of objects like this:

```
const dataNodes = [
  {
    name: 'nameFirstNode',
    port: '80',
    ip_urls: ['http://10.0.4.16/some-text/some-text/']
  },
  {
    name: 'nameSecondNode',
    port: '81',
    ip_urls: [
      'http://172.16.1.102/some-text/some-text/',
      'http://10.1.31.131/some-text/some-text/'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'nameThirdNode',
    port: '82',
    ip_urls: [
      'http://10.1.30.115/some-text/some-text/',
      'http://172.16.1.116/some-text/some-text/'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'nameForthNode',
    port: '83',
    ip_urls: 'http://10.1.31.173/some-text/some-text/'
  }
]
```

and like a result I want to sort it ascending by IP. like this, am i right.

```
const dataNodes = [
  {
    name: 'nameThirdNode',
    port: '82',
    ip_urls: [
      'http://10.1.30.115/some-text/some-text/', // the less
      'http://172.16.1.116/some-text/some-text/'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'nameSecondNode',
    port: '81',
    ip_urls: [
      'http://172.16.1.102/some-text/some-text/',
      'http://10.1.31.131/some-text/some-text/' // the less
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'nameForthNode',
    port: '83',
    ip_urls: 'http://10.1.31.173/some-text/some-text/'
  },
  {
    name: 'nameFirstNode',
    port: '80',
    ip_urls: ['http://172.16.1.118/some-text/some-text/']
  }
]
```

i understand that i can take the IP in every string with regular expression like this:

```
const regExpIp = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/;
```

but the most question how to go through the array using the desired property (ip_urls) and sort ascending.

Thank you very much)

Comment: Do you need to sort `dataNodes ` or just the `ip_urls` array? Check `Array.forEach` and `Array.sort` functions

Comment: yeah, i should sort dataNodes finally based on sort ip_urls